# Discussion Forum

Tags: safecracker, forum, discussion

Is there any way to make the discussion forum have better clean URLs?

At the moment it defaults to `/forum/viewforum/7/`, but it would be nice to have something like `/forum/viewforum/expressionengine/`or `/forum/viewthread/test-topic/`.

The only other solution I can think of is to use [Channel Form](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/), and build something like similar to a forum.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to keep the discussion forum URLs as it is. Because at this moment whole plugin made of '/forum/viewforum/7/' type of URLs and there are no ways to change it. If you want then you need to customize whole plugin. But it becomes very difficult and lengthy.